# Runner file showing Error "Cucumber.class can't be resolved" if kept in src/main/java folder

Tags: cucumber

Cucumber.class in Runner file showing error at line @RunWith(Cucumber.class) when put in src/main/java folder but work fine when put in src/test/java folder. Why is the reason for this Error? I have read other posts similar to this but none of them provide complete answer.

Comment: in the POM is the `scope` of the cucumber jars set to `test`?

Comment: Yes, it was test. On removing this scope it's not giving error if put in main. Thanks @Grasshopper